# Is there a way to improve performance of searching using filtered alias in ElasticSearch?

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

I am trying to optimize searching speed on my index containing text data. My query is very complex, there are lots of bool queries at many levels. Each query has also a filter query, which narrows the search area. My idea was to create filtered alias (with filter query) on my index and search through my query (without the part with filter query), but id didn't improve searching speed.
My second idea is to make reindex on my filtered index (every day for example) and then search on new index (that decreased speed a lot), but the data comes to index simultanously in real time, so this solution is not appropriate for the production environment.
Could you advice any solution how to deal with that?

Comment: what sort of performance do you get and what do you want?

Comment: I wanted to decrease searching speed by searching on less data (filtered alias or reindex filtered index). But both ideas are not proper. Searching on filtered alias doesnn't decrease the speed and making reindex while main index is changing is not applicable to production environment